# prove sum of elements of subsets are different

Tags: number-theory

The set S contains 18 distinct (but unknown) four-digit positive integers. Linda calculates the sum of the elements in each non-empty subset of S. Prove that it is impossible for all of these sums to be distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The number of subsets of $S$ is $2^{|S|}$ where $|S|$ is the number of elements in $S$. Excluding the empty set, Linda calculated $2^{18}-1=262143$ sums. The smallest possible sum is $1000$, which corresponds to the singleton subset $\{1000\}$. The largest possible sum is $9982+9983+\cdots + 9999=179829$, which corresponds to the subset $\{9982,9983,\cdots,9999\}$. All possible values for these sums are between $1000$ and $179829$. There are $178829$ of them, but usually less because you may not be able to reach the minimum $1000$ and maximum $179829$ all the time. But Linda calculated $262143$ sums. By the pigeonhole principle, at least two of these sums are the same.